# Rewriting a date hierarchy into a 'yyyy-mm-dd' slug

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, mod-rewrite

I am building a magazine website with an `issue` custom post type. The slugs for each issue follow the format `YYYY-MM-DD` according to the issue's publish date. Currently the permalinks are set up as `http://host/magazine/2014-06-08` but I would like them to be accessed through the URL `http://host/magazine/2014/06/08`.

Here is what I'm currently doing in my `functions.php`:

```
$issue_structure = '/magazine/%issue%';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%issue%", '(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', "issue=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('issue', $issue_structure, false);
```

I tried adding this to my .htaccess file:
`RewriteRule ^magazine/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2}) /magazine/$1-$2-$3 [QSA,L]`

And I also tried added this to my WP_Rewrite rules:
`add_rewrite_rule('magazine/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})', 'magazine/$matches[1]-$matches[2]-$matches[3]', 'top');`

Neither of those approaches have worked, either separately or in combination. And I was careful to flush my rewrite rules. In fact, there's no evidence of that `add_rewrite_rule` call in my [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) list, so I suspect I'm not using it correctly.

Another (hacky) thing I tried was manually tweaking the `post_name` field in the database to be `2014/06/08` and switching up the rewrite tag to be `$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%issue%", '(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})', "issue=");` but that didn't work either.

What else should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal rewrite rules have to point to `index.php` and set the proper query vars for WordPress to be able to load the requested object:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'magazine/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/?',
    'index.php?issue=$matches[1]-$matches[2]-$matches[3]',
    'top'
);
```

That should get incoming requests to resolve correctly, however, that's only half the task. If you call `the_permalink` for your posts, you'll still get the format you defined when you registered your post type. To fix that you have to filter [`post_type_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link) to output the URLs in the correct format.